# Calculate the probability of someone breaking a world record time

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to calculate the probability of someone breaking the world record time in a race, I have data about previous races from 1984 till 2015 containing the times people have gotten. The world record has been broken twice. I now need to calculate what the chance is of someone breaking the world record again. Can anyone tell me how to tackle a problem like this=
cheers

Comment: This is not a well-defined mathematical problem. The improvements in records may be related to systematic improvements in training method and the like. If you want to model them probabilistically, you need to say how. Or you could ask about what a good model might be, but that's different from "calculating a probability", which presupposes a probabilistic model.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for an estimate of the *time until the record is broken* instead? Such events are considered in extreme value theory.

Comment: Your question is not framed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of such kinds of events cannot be calculated,  since it depends on many factors like improvements in training equipments, average diet of the participants, temperature at the time of race and even what kind of shoes the participants are wearing. These are just a few examples. Actually, there are infinite number of such factors.

However, your question asks the probability of a person breaking the record again. You did not give a fixed time interval for this to happen. So, given INFINITE time, I believe the probability of someone breaking the record again will be almost equal to 1 owing to advancements in training.